# Is it valid js syntax?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        el: $('body');
        this.template          = "<div></div>";
        this.model             = new Model;
        this.render();
    }
)
```

I've found this code in one project, and was puzzled by `el: $('body');` inside of the initialize code.

At first i thought it's just typo, and it had to be

```
View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function() {
        this.template          = "<div></div>";
        this.model             = new Model;
        this.render();
    }
)
```

But then i've found it in a few another files.

Is it some kind of 'hacky' way to set `el` or just nonsense?

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: `el:` is a label, the return value of `$('body')` is not used --> this is just nonsense.

Comment: If el is inside initialize function how could we use it out side to set view??

Comment: @SergioTulentsev reviewing one commercial project, can't say details due to privacy reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [valid syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), but does for sure not do what you might expect. Here, it's just nonsense.